# Fiddler: Is it possible to replace part of URL using OnBeforeResponse function?

Tags: javascript, replace, fiddler, jscript.net

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.youtube.com") && oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){

                oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
                oSession.utilReplaceInResponse("old string","new string");
            }
```

Please tell me if I'm using the above script correctly or not.

Basically, How do I  to replace/hide the word `dolphin` from the search query ? I don't want the client browser(my Google Chrome) to see it by any means.

Example : http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=`dolphin`&page=3.

If this is not possible with Fiddler,then what other application do you recommend?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* replace anything in the url inside `OnBeforeResponse`, but doing so won't do anything useful, because the URL has already been sent to the server by then, so changing it that late has no visible impact to anything outside of Fiddler.

If you want to change the URL, do so inside `OnBeforeRequest`. In your FiddlerScript, look for the `urlreplace` handler to see how that works.

Comment: With `oSession.utilReplaceInResponse`, I can literally replace any string inside the source page.Now, In the same sense, How can I replace a small parameter in the URL sent by the server? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Servers don't send URLs.

Comment: `changing it that late has no visible impact to anything outside of Fiddler.` Let me be clear, If I remove a small parameter, Will that parameter be still visible in web browser's address bar? Thank you

Comment: When I say that changing the URL inside `OnBeforeResponse` will have `no visible impact to anything outside Fiddler`, I'm a little confused about why you would ask `Will a browser's address bar change?` Beyond that, is there some reason you don't just, you know, *try it*?

Comment: In `OnBeforeResponse`, I replaced querystring `test` with `StackOveflow`, it shows properly in Fiddler, but not in Google chrome. i.imgur.com/4dgvIYX.png . Please help, I really need a solution.

Comment: @jaridwilders: And that's **exactly** what you should expect given that this is **exactly** what I told you would happen. Put your code inside `OnBeforeRequest` as I told you.

Comment: Let me be more clear, I appended `-adult` to search query, so that it will not show me adult videos. My kids will notice, if they read the address bar, I don't want to them to notice the tampering. any solutions? I want to do this with Fiddler.

Comment: I can change HTML content in `OnBeforeResponse` but not a query or a parameter in URL. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @jaridwilders You can change `a parameter in URL` whenever you want. But doing so *after you've already requested the URL* obviously doesn't affect anything. Imagine you type a letter `Please send me a cheese sandwich` on your PC. You print it out and you put it in the mailbox. Then you go back to your computer and change `cheese` to `peanut butter and jelly`. What kind of sandwich do you think you will receive?

Comment: There is also my Dad(Fiddler proxy) standing at the door, who receives the mail, strikes out `cheese` and writes `peanut butter and jelly`, and then gives it to me. I know it's a cheese sandwich, even though it says "peanut butter and jelly". Can I  achieve this with Fiddler?

Comment: The browser sends the URL it is requesting to the server. The browser doesn't then ask the server `hey, by the way, what URL did I ask for?` because it already knows what URL it asked for.