# Javascript: Append a string to search query after clicking submit/search button

Tags: javascript, append, search-engine

In this case, Let's take Google as example:

The code is JScript .NET, which is basically a .NET version of Javascript. Regardless of language, Anyone with appending type of skill can answer my question.

This code is used in `Fiddler`(It's a Man-in-the-middle proxy)

```
if (oSession.uriContains("&q=")) // oSession is a Fiddler object session // uriContains() function, checks for case-insensitive string from the URI
    {
        var str = oSession.fullUrl;
        var sAppend = "test1+test2+test3";
        if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
        {
            oSession.fullUrl = str.replace( "&q=","&q="+sAppend);
        }
    }
```

For those who are confused, It says, If `&q=` is present in the URI, replace/append `&q=` with `&q=test1+test2+test3`

**Problem**: It appends  `test1+test2+test3` instantly, when it sees `&q=` in the URL.

Basically, how do I make it wait until I click the submit/search button

Thank you.

Comment: You could attach your code to the submit event?

Comment: My "appending type of skill" varies from language to language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Identifying your problem

I'm assuming:

1. you want to use Fiddler for your solution (since you're already using it)
2. you've figured out how to alter the request URI (as shown in your example), and your problem is that **you want to target only those requests where the "search" button was clicked**, not auto-submitted searches

Isolating those requests that stem from the search button being pressed on google is not straightforward, but I came up with a hack that seems to work.  Basically, the `oq` (original query) get parameter is **only added when the user explicitly hits button/enter key**, so we test for its presence in order to identify such requests.

### Solution

In your `OnBeforeRequest` method in Fiddler `Handlers` class (where you're already putting your code), we'll:

1. Check that request is **to www.google.com** and **contains `q` parameter**

   - If true, log (in the fiddler log) that a query was submitted to google.com &
     highlight request in pink
2. Check that request **contains `oq` parameter** (original query)

   - If true, log alert that submit button was pressed & highlight request in Light Forest Green

### Code

```
if(oSession.HostnameIs('www.google.com') && oSession.uriContains("&q=")){
    FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString('query submitted to google.com...');
    oSession['ui-backcolor'] = 'pink'; //highlight this request

    //test for original query
    if(oSession.uriContains('&oq=')){
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString('SUBMIT BUTTON OR ENTER CLICKED (probably)');
        oSession['ui-backcolor'] = '#369369'; //highlight in Light Forest Green
        //whatever sort of request manipulation you want to do here...
    }

}
```

### Other notes:

- I'm assuming you want to *prepend* your query string to the existing `q` value, i.e. `q=Hello` will become `q=test1+test2+test3Hello`.  If you want to replace it you need More Regex.
- Depending on your needs, Naomi or Ahmed's request may be better (it's in-browser, not in fiddler).
- [Modifying a request or response in Fiddler](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-07-15/understanding-fiddlerscript)
- [Understanding Fiddlerscript](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-07-15/understanding-fiddlerscript)

Comment: Your solution is perfect for me.Also, what does `FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString` actually do? Is it necessary for the code to work? Thank you so much.

Comment: The `LogString` statements just output a message in the fiddler log; it's mostly for demo/debugging here & no you don't need it.  Same goes for changing the background color- it's just a visual indicator that your script is working as expected & is not necessary (tho I recommend keeping it, it's useful IMO).

Comment: Could you please check this link, very similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/q/25892688/3987368

Comment: See the last two resources above under "other notes."  You've been given a fish as well as a fishing lesson.  Now go cast your line & stop asking for more fish. :)  (you are asking for fully working solutions one after the next & it doesn't seem like you are trying stuff/working to find a solution on your own.)

Comment: I can't see no fish, I need to find a good fishing spot.:-) (Just a doubt, Is it possible to remove a small URL parameter sent by the server via Fiddler?) A hint would be nice. Thank you

Comment: @jaridwilders Just like the guy on the other question said, "Server's don't send URLs."  I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), step back & ask your high level question.  What is your goal?

Comment: Let me be more clear. In relation to my question, I want the opposite results, I want to detach/remove a querystring before it reaches my web browser.In `OnBeforeResponse` I replaced querystring `test` with `StackOveflow`, it shows properly in Fiddler, but not in Google chrome. http://i.imgur.com/4dgvIYX.png .If this is not possible with Fiddler,then what other solutions do you recommend?

Comment: Misdirecting someone about the page they're on is a very sketchy goal.  What is your goal?

Comment: I appended `-adult` to search query, so that it will not show me adult videos. My kids will notice, if they read the address bar, I don't want to them to notice the tampering. Any solutions? I want to do this with Fiddler, if possible.

Comment: I can change HTML content in OnBeforeResponse but not a query or a parameter in URL. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @jaridwilders basically you are trying to trick your users (your children).  This sort of trickery, if the browser supported it, would be a MAJOR security problem, and there's not really any legitimate reason to do this, so No, you can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well in Javascript you can bind actions to events. In your case the event is the `submit` of the form For example:

```
function addEventsToHTML(){
    var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
    form1.onsubmit = submitHandler;
    function submitHandler(){
        alert("You just submit: "+this.email.value);
    }
}
```

If you want to bind it on click you can do:

```
object.onclick=function(){myScript};
```

Or

```
object.addEventListener("click", myScript);
```

**Note**: The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Comment: I want to test this code specifically on Google Search. How can I do this?

Comment: go to a website like css-tricks.com (i choose this because i am not sure if the Google form ID is auto generated or not, so that you might not get the same ID always). Anyhow, just type this into the console and try to search `document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener("click", function() { alert('OK')});`